# Make external identifier property values to URLs in a Wikibase

Tags: wikibase

In Wikidata, external identifier properties can have an associated "formatter URL" that will allow Wikidata to format a URL for the property value based on the identifier, e.g., https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P10831 has set the https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1630 with "https://ordregister.dk/id/$1" which means that any item that use P10831 will get a URL, e.g., "COR.38799" with P10831 will be linked as https://ordregister.dk/id/COR.38799

I have tried a similar method on a cloud-based Wikibase, https://dreams.wikibase.cloud, but no link appears. For instance, an external identifier property https://dreams.wikibase.cloud/wiki/Property:P40 has the property https://dreams.wikibase.cloud/wiki/Property:P4 set to "https://daieproddreamspdfsto.blob.core.windows.net/files/$1", but items using P40 do not display a link.

Is it possible to make external identifier value links? Where is the option?

Comment: Is this any help? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation/Advanced_configuration#Define_links_for_external_identifiers

Answer (score 2):

As @will-hanley's link to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation/Advanced_configuration#Define_links_for_external_identifiers shows the property for external linking can be set with the `$wgWBRepoSettings['formatterUrlProperty']` in the `LocalSettings.php`.
For Wikibase.cloud instances, this variable is, however, not directly available. Instead one should link ones Wikibase property in the settings (under "Features" and "Mapping Properties to wikidata"), so a "My Wikibase" property is linked to P1630 in Wikidata. After a while (hours?) the cache will be refreshed and the links appear.

This was explained by Laurence Parry in the wikibase-cloud mailing list: https://lists.wikimedia.org/hyperkitty/list/wikibase-cloud@lists.wikimedia.org/thread/7HPE53X6PQXTJ2TEVGT6RBB5HLDOT2VF/